# Langrange Multiplier to Function $x^2-y^2-z^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Im Trying To Find The min and max values of function
$$f(x, y, z) = x^2-y^2-z^2$$

At constraint $g(x, y, z) = x^2+y^2+z^2-1$.

My Solution :

I'm using gradient to find the partial derivatives of each variables so :

$\nabla f'(x, y, z) = <2x, -2y, -2z>$

$\nabla g'(x, y, z) = <2x, 2y, 2z>$

Set up :
$$\nabla (f) = \lambda \nabla(g)$$
$$ 2x = \lambda(2x)$$
$$-2y = \lambda(2y)$$
$$-2z = \lambda(2z)$$

At $x^2+y^2+z^2-1$

Solving for $\lambda$:
$$\lambda = \frac{2x}{2x} = 1$$
$$\lambda = -\frac{2y}{2y} = -1$$
$$\lambda = -\frac{2z}{2z} = -1$$

Im basically stuck at here because the lambdas are not giving any variable and only constant to sub into the constraint (which is confusing).

Anyone can tell me what i did wrong here?

Ps: i'm writing on a touch device.

Comment: Looks like a good start.  For the rest: $\lambda$ can't simultaneously be $1$ and $-1$.  Say $\lambda =1$, what points does that give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in this post is to divide by $x$, $y$, $z$ without considering whether they are zero or not.

If $2y\lambda=-2y$ and $2x\lambda=2x$ then there is a solution $\lambda=1$ if you put $y=0$, and similarly if $x=0$ then $\lambda=-1$ is perfectly OK.

Physically, $x,y$ and $z$ are on a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, and then we are minimising/maximising $x^2-y^2-z^2$, so we don't need to use Lagrange multipliers. We can add the constraint to $f$ to eliminate $y$ and $z$ and get $f(x)=2x^2$ and then minimise/maximise that.

Obviously the minimum is $x=0$ and the maximum is $x=\pm1$.

But assuming that this is an exercise in practising the Lagrange multipliers, let's do it that way. $x=0$ corresponds to $\lambda=-1$ and $y^2+z^2=1$, and $x=\pm1$ corresponds to $y^2=z^2=0$ which is our $\lambda=1$ case above.

Comment: Thank you! Never thought of the possibility of the variables equals to zero.

Comment: @Celina: every time you divide anything by anything else, you should ask yourself "do I really know that the denominator is nonzero?"

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the max and min via the langrange equation? How do you find the max and min value equals to +-1 and 0? @Suzu Hirose

Comment: Because $f(x)=2x^2$ under the constraint, and we know that $x$ is limited to the range $[-1,1]$, it's clear that the minimum of $f$ is at $x=0$ and the maximum is at $x=\pm1$.

Comment: If there's any way that you can solve the whole equation using only Langrange multiplier only? It would be helpful if you can help @SuzuHirose

Comment: Celina, I have solved it using the Lagrange multiplier only. I have solved it both ways. If you use the Lagrange multiplier then you must have either $x=0$ or $y=z=0$. Then you just need to work out which is maximum and which is minimum. At this stage I beg you to please review the answer very carefully before asking another question in the comments.